# Display new table in the database MVC4 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am cluless, i dont know why my database its showing in the deafult connection in the database , I am programing in C# MVC4 asp.net using razor technology,

here is my UserAccountContext

```
public class UserAccountContext : DbContext
{
    public UserAccountContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }

    // Methods...
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    // Methods...

    public IQueryable<UserAccount> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<UserAccount> query = this.UserAccounts;

        return query;
    }

    public UserAccount GetSingle(string _UserName)
    {
        UserAccount Query = this.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == _UserName);

        return Query;
    }

    public void Save(UserAccount _UserAccount)
    {
        if (_UserAccount.ID == 0)
        {
            this.UserAccounts.Add(_UserAccount);
            this.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            this.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my UserAccount Model

```
public class UserAccount
{
    // Attributes turns into fields in the database
    // These attributes persist in the database
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string WhoVoted { get; set; }
    public double NumberOfVotes { get; set; }

    // The following attributes will not persist in the DB
    public string UserErrorMessage = string.Empty; // Volatile Variable

    // Methods...

    public UserAccount() { } //Constructor... This is needed to create the DB Table

    public UserAccount(int _UserId, string _UserName) // Other Constructor
    {
        this.ID = 0;
        this.UserId = _UserId;
        this.UserName = _UserName;
        this.NumberOfVotes = 0.0;
        this.WhoVoted = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I have everything, i dont know how to deal with the database , Lookking forward for any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you set the connectionString in the web.config

Comment: open the web.config file and check the   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbName.mdf;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings> something similair to this

Comment: Follow this link it may help you to create table in your database [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Yeah it is like that

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyVote-20141126040642;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyVote-20141126040642.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: still not appearing, what to do??